# How to find third horizontal tangent to $r=1-\sin\theta$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Given the curve $r=1-\sin\theta, $ I'm supposed to find the horizontal tangents.  I took the derivative of x and y to find that...

$$dy/dx = \frac{\cos\theta-2\cos\theta \sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta}$$

I set the derivative equal to zero and get

$$0=\cos\theta-2\cos\theta \sin\theta$$

$$2\cos\theta \sin\theta = \cos \theta$$

Dividing by $\cos$ gives

$$2\sin\theta=1$$ which has two solutions between $0$ and $2\pi$.

These appear correct when I graph it, too, as $\theta = \pi/6, 5\pi/6$ both point to horizontal tangents.

But it's obvious that $3\pi/2$ is also a horizontal tangent.  How would I have known this from the math, without looking at the graph?

[image]

Comment: "*Dividing by cos*" $\;-\;$ Watch your step here.

Comment: What do you.mean @dxiv

Comment: If you divide an equation by *something*, you must first make sure that *something* $\ne 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing by $\cos(\theta)$: Note the $\cos(\theta)$ could be zero, in which case it doesn't make sense to straight away divide $\cos(\theta)$.

There so there should be some case analysis:

> $\text{Case } 1: \cos{\theta} \neq 0$

Then $$2\sin(\theta) = 1 \\ \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$$

> $\text{Case } 2: \cos{\theta} = 0$

Then $$\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$$
However, by substituting into the equation for the derivative,
the denominator, $\sin^2\theta−\cos^2\theta−\sin\theta$ becomes $0$ when $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Hence, the derivative does not exist at $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore we dismiss the root $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so the roots to the derivative, and hence the horizontal tangents to the curve are: $$\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$$.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for the comment, I've made some edits to the answer so hopefully it is now complete.

Comment: (This comment is towards OP) I am writing this as comment because I dont think its enough to fill an answer, rather extend one. I feel the concepts behind $\cos{\theta}=0$ as solution be explained, as to why it cannot be _divided_ from the equation. $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = 0$$. Hence, $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = 0$ is a solution, and since $y = r\sin{\theta}$ is parametrized, then $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = \dots \cos{\theta}$ would appear somewhere. Finally, this is why $\cos{\theta} = 0$ is essential in obtaining the solutions, and should not be _divided_.